# How to get base64 value from function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to create dummy data for mongodb, part of the data is pictures which needs to be converted first to base64 and then i need the display them.

Here is my controller

```
    var buffer = require('buffer');
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var users_model;

    var PageUsersController = function () {
        users_model = require('../models/users_model');

    }

    module.exports = PageUsersController;

    var pic_binary;
    function encode_base64(filename){
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,'../foo/',filename),function(error,data){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }else{
                var buf = Buffer.from(data);
                var base64 = buf.toString('base64');
                pic_binary = base64;
                console.log(pic_binary); // returns result.
                return base64;
            }
        });
    }

    encode_base64('user_pic.jpg');


    PageUsersController.getUserDetails = function (cb) {

        var flat_details = [
            {


                user_name: "john",
                user_pic:pic_binary, // always return undefined

            }
        ];
        return cb(null, flat_details);

    }
```

How can i pass the mongodb schema the variable 'pic_binary' that holds the results of the encoding?

I've tried to set the function's value into a variable and then passing it... but i get undefined no matter how i'm setting the result as variable

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Should have used Synchronized :

```
     var buff = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../user_pic/','profile_pic.png'));
     var base64data = buff.toString('base64');

     var flat_details = [
    {

        user_pic:base64data , // problem solved.
    }
   ];
```